# When UIImagePickerController is finished taking a photo, go to camera view

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I take a photo with UIImagePickerController, and when I click the "use" button, go back to camera view to take another photo?

Answer (score 0):

After you get

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

just go right back in with a new `UIImagePicker`

Here's an example: https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake -- just call `takePhotoOrChooseFromLibrary` directly from `gotPhoto`.