# Is it possible to re-present the camera after taking a picture and selecting "Use" with ImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

After taking a picture using the ImagePickerController and selecting "Use", I want the camera screen to appear again to continue taking more shots, how do I achieve this so I can keep taking shots without stopping? I am not using AVFoundation but ImagePickerController.

Comment: See this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245964/when-uiimagepickercontroller-is-finished-taking-a-photo-go-to-camera-view

Answer (score 0):

If you set `showsCameraControls` of your `UIImagePickerController` to `NO` and provide your own camera controls you can take multiple pictures after each other and dismiss the interface when you see fit.